# How did they factorise the algebra in this step?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

[image]

$$16=12-3+\frac{3}{k}+(8-\frac{3}{k})e^{-k}.$$
$\implies$
$$(8-\frac{3}{k})(1-e^{-k})=1.$$

Is there some algebra trick or standard strategy that I a missing or failing to see?

Comment: What is the source of this screenshot?

Comment: Weird, all I can get is the same thing but replace $1$ by $15$

Comment: Isn't it just $16-12+3-\frac3k-e^{-k}(8-\frac3k)+\color{blue}1=8-\frac3k-e^{-k}(8-\frac3k)=(8-\frac3k)(1-e^{-k})=\color{blue}1$ ?

Comment: $$16=12-3+\frac{3}{k}+\left(8-\frac{3}{k}\right)e^{-k}\implies$$$$16-12+3-\frac{3}{k}-\left(8-\frac{3}{k}\right)e^{-k}=0\implies$$$$7-\frac{3}{k}-\left(8-\frac{3}{k}\right)e^{-k}=0\implies$$$$\color{red}{1\,+\,}7-\frac{3}{k}-\left(8-\frac{3}{k}\right)e^{-k}=\color{red}{1\,+\,}0\implies$$$$8-\frac{3}{k}-\left(8-\frac{3}{k}\right)e^{-k}=1\implies$$$$\color{red}{\left(8-\frac{3}{k}\right)}\!\color{blue}{\cdot\!1-}\color{red}{\left(8-\frac{3}{k}\right)}\!\color{blue}{\cdot\!e^{-k}}=1\implies$$$$\color{red}{\left(8-\frac{3}{k}\right)}\color{blue}{\left(1-e^{-k}\right)}=1\,.$$